# Help with cardinality of infinite sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone walk me through the process of solving this.  I'm learning about the cardinality of infinite sets but I'm not really sure where to start.

Define the set $4Z^+$ as the set of positive integers that are multiples of 4 (i.e. 4, 8, 12, 16, ...) Show that the set $4Z^+$ is countably infinite by identifying a function whose domain is the natural numbers $N$ and whose co-domain is the set $4Z^+$

Comment: List the first few elements of each set. How might you pair them?

Comment: what specifically are you having trouble with? Do you know the meaning of “co-domain” for example? Do you understand what the question is asking? Or...

Comment: hint: write out the first few positive terms and factor out a four. this should give you an idea on how to construct a function from the naturals into $4Z^+$, and maybe even an idea on how to extend it to $4Z$

Comment: "List the first few elements of each set"...there is only one set and it is already infinite.  I'm not understanding what else I can add to that.

Comment: The prompt is wrong. There is a function whose domain is N and whose co-domain is {1} (just map every natural number to 1), but the latter is clearly finite. You need a *bijective* function.

Comment: so my domain is {4,8,12,16,20.........n} and my co-domain is {1,2,3,4,5,6......n}? like that?...

Comment: No, you want the set of *all* positive integer multiples of 4 (not just up to some $n$) and the set of *all" natural numbers (not just up to some $n$).

Comment: So my function is $f(n) = 4n, n \in N$   ?

Comment: @Cackling Muse- Yes that’s right (your function).

Comment: Ok good...I'm getting somewhere...Now I have to prove that the function identified is a one-to-one correspondence between the set $N$ and the set $4Z^+$

Comment: This is what I have so far.

Suppose $y$ is a particular but arbitrarily chosen positive multiple of 4.

We must show that $x$ in the natural numbers, $x\in N$ such that $f(n)=y$

$4x=y$     solve for $x$

$4x$ / $4 = y$ / $4$     by division

$x = y$ / $4$


Since $y = 2k + 2 $ for some integer $k$ $\geq 0$

We have $x = 2k+2$ / $4$   Not sure where to go from here or if I'm even doing it right.